# How can I prove that this function is not complex differentiable anywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

I am trying to show that the function $f(z) = z + \overline{z}$ is not complex differentiable for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. To do this, I have tried to show that the limit
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow w} \frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z-w} = \lim_{z \rightarrow w} \frac{(z-w) + (\overline{z} - \overline{w})}{z-w}
$$
does not exist for any $w$. However, I have been unable to work out how to do this.

As an alternative attempt, I have tried to use the substitution $z = x + iy$, giving
$$
f(z) = f(x + iy) = (x+iy) + (x-iy) = 2x
$$
and then use this to show that $f(z)$ is not complex differentiable. However, I was again unsure of how to proceed from here.

Could anyone help me with this proof?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the limits if you approach $w$ along the vertical (imaginary) or horizontal (real) axis.

Comment: +1 In my opinion, this is a good approach for the general problem of showing something isn't (complex) differentiable: take a limit from two different directions and show that the limits aren't the same; this shows that it's not differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

In principle your first approach already tells all,
$$
\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\frac{\bar h}h=\frac{\bar h^2}{|h|^2}
$$
The possible values cover the full unit circle, independent of the size of $h$, there is no unique limit.

Answer (score 0):

The open mapping theorem is your friend :-).

Note that $f$ is real valued everywhere and non constant. If $f$ was analytic at $z$, it would be an open map which is impossible, hence $f$ is not analytic at any $z$.